# Django class based custom error page handler

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, http-status-code-404

Is it possible to write a class based (not function) custom error page handler?

for example this:

```
def handler404(request, *args, **argv):
    response = render_to_response('404.html', {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 404
    return response
```

but with class